# Galera, estou usando um overflow em um componente aqui, porém ele não mostra todo o conteúdo, fica cortado em uma parte. Poderiam me ajudar?

Tags: css, react, styled-components

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`export const OptionBar = styled.div'

```
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
padding: 0 15%;
font-size: 1.6rem;
transition: all 0.4s;
align-items: flex-end;
overflow-x: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 95px;
padding: 10px;
';`
```

Comment: você tem o código fonte? se você estiver usando bootstrap e colocar este css, vai dar problema.

Comment: estou usando styled-components